# Gulp - How do i chain together tasks or streams that use different src?

Tags: gulp

I want to all perform actions **in stream** but from multiple sources then deploy all at the end, how can i do that in gulp either in the same task or by combining tasks?

For example:

```
return gulp.src('/dir1/*.js')
  .pipe(..)
  .pipe(..)
  .gulp.src('/dir2/*.css') 
  .pipe(gif('some-particular-file.css', xxx))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

also let me add that I dont want to have to filter like this:

```
   gulp.src(['/dir1/*.js', '/dir2/*.css'])
       .pipe(gif(*.js, xxx)
       .pipe(gif(*.css, xxx)
       .gulp.dest('appy'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**gulp 3.x**

Use the [`gulp-add-src`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-add-src) package:

```
var addSrc = require('gulp-add-src');

return gulp.src('/dir1/*.js')
  .pipe(..)
  .pipe(..)
  .pipe(addSrc('/dir2/*.css')) 
  .pipe(gif('some-particular-file.css', xxx))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

**gulp 4.x**

`gulp.src()` can act as a passthrough stream by using the [`passthrough` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/API.md#optionspassthrough):

```
return gulp.src('/dir1/*.js')
  .pipe(..)
  .pipe(..)
  .pipe(gulp.src('/dir2/*.css', {passthrough:true})) 
  .pipe(gif('some-particular-file.css', xxx))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [merge-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream)

```
gulp.task('test', function() {
  var bootstrap = gulp.src('bootstrap/js/*.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/bootstrap'));

  var jquery = gulp.src('jquery.cookie/jquery.cookie.js')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/jquery'));

  return merge(bootstrap, jquery);
});
```

Source: [Using multiple sources in one task](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/using-multiple-sources-in-one-task.md#using-multiple-sources-in-one-task)